# get the last modified date of tables using bigquery tables GET api

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the list of tables and their last_modified_date using bigquery REST API.
In the bigquery API explorer I am getting all the fields correctly but when I use the api from Python code its returning 'None' for modified date.

This is the code written for the same in python

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project='temp')
datasets = list(client.list_datasets())

for dataset in datasets:
    print dataset.dataset_id

for dataset in datasets:
    for table in dataset.list_tables():
        print table.table_id
        print table.created
        print table.modified
```

In this code I am getting created date correctly but modified date is 'None' for all the tables.

Comment: Try `print table` and/or `dir(table)`. Which other attributes does it have?

Comment: modified is one of it's attributes but it is returning value 'None' for modified.

Comment: When you list tables ([`tables.list` behind the scenes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list#response)) the only included attributes appear to be `creationTime` and `expirationTime`. I think you need to `get`/`reload` the table (I'm not sure of the correct API) instead so fetch additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite sure which version of the API you are using but I suspect the [latest versions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/dataset.py#L283) do not have the method `dataset.list_tables()`.

Still, this is one way of getting last modified field, see if this works for you (or gives you some idea on how to get this data):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('/key.json')

dataset_list = list(client.list_datasets())
for dataset_item in dataset_list:
    dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_item.reference)
    tables_list = list(client.list_tables(dataset))

    for table_item in tables_list:
        table = client.get_table(table_item.reference)
        print "Table {} last modified: {}".format(
            table.table_id, table.modified)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the last modified time from only one table:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
    
def get_last_bq_update(project, dataset, table_name):
    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('/key.json')
    table_id = f"{project}.{dataset}.{table_name}"
    table = client.get_table(table_id)
    print(table.modified)
```

Comment: Hi :), please add a little description to your answer.